# SQL Join using outside variable

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to join two tables together, one table contains an ID, and a TIME_STAMP when the item was entered.

| ID | TIME_IN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:00:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 |
| 2 | 30-JUN-2023 07:00:00 |
| 2 | 29-JUN-2023 12:00:00 |

The second table contains a list of the ID's movements, categorised by a 'COMMAND', 1 meaning entered, 2 meaning left.

| ID | TIME_STAMP | COMMAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 26-JUN-2023 08:10:00 | 2 |

I want to join these tables to create a table as below.

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:00:00 | 29-JUN-2023 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 | 28-JUN-2023 03:10:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 | 27-JUN-2023 19:10:00 |

I tried the below, and it returns what I expected - the latest times for all, as below.

```
SELECT 
A."TIME_IN",
MOVE.TIME_OUT,
FROM TIMESIN A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
  ID,
  MAX(TIME_STAMP) AS "TIME_OUT"
  FROM MOVEMENTTAB M
  WHERE COMMAND = 2
  GROUP BY ID
) 
MOVE ON MOVE.ID = A.ID AND HIST.TIME_OUT > A.TIME_IN
```

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |

So I thought if I swapped the MAX for MIN that it would return me the lowest time for each instance, but I figured I'm getting the below, although the TIME_OUT column appears as NULL, as the 26th Jun is omitted from the 'TIMESIN' table.

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:00:00 | 26-JUN-2023 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:00:00 | 26-JUN-2023 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 | 26-JUN-2023 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 | 26-JUN-2023 08:10:00 |

Is there any way to use a variable within the JOIN from outside, like `WHERE TIME_OUT > A.TIME_IN`, or is there a better solution I can't think of?

I have tried using a SELECT statement add a column, but this slows down the process loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join and `FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY` to get the latest time-in:

```sql
SELECT m.id,
       t.time_in,
       m.time_stamp AS time_out
FROM   movementtab m
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT time_in
         FROM   timesin t
         WHERE  t.time_in <= m.time_stamp
         AND    t.id = m.id
         ORDER BY t.time_in DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE timesin (ID, TIME_IN) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '08:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-28' + INTERVAL '03:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-27' + INTERVAL '19:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE movementtab (ID, TIME_STAMP, COMMAND) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '12:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '08:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-28' + INTERVAL '03:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-27' + INTERVAL '19:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-26' + INTERVAL '08:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 12:00:00 | 2023-06-30 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-29 08:00:00 | 2023-06-29 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-28 03:00:00 | 2023-06-28 03:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-27 19:00:00 | 2023-06-27 19:10:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Egl-3tGs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to concatenate the two tables and then use the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function to find the most-recent preceding time-in for each time-out:

```sql
SELECT id,
       time_in,
       ts AS time_out
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         ts,
         command,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE command WHEN 1 THEN ts END) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) AS time_in
  FROM   (
    SELECT id, time_in AS ts, 1 AS command
    FROM   timesin
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time_stamp, command
    FROM   movementtab
    WHERE  command = 2
  )
)
WHERE  command = 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE timesin (ID, TIME_IN) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '08:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-28' + INTERVAL '03:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-27' + INTERVAL '19:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE movementtab (ID, TIME_STAMP, COMMAND) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '12:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '08:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-28' + INTERVAL '03:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-27' + INTERVAL '19:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-26' + INTERVAL '08:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | 2023-06-26 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-27 19:00:00 | 2023-06-27 19:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-28 03:00:00 | 2023-06-28 03:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-29 08:00:00 | 2023-06-29 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 12:00:00 | 2023-06-30 12:10:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mP9XHQ2G)