# FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY within JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I had previously asked a question about including a variable from the outer SQL, within a JOIN statement:

> [SQL Join using outside variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592151/sql-join-using-outside-variable)

The answer provided did answer my problem but performance was poor and took over a minute to produce the results.

In the example I have two tables:

| ID | TIME_IN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:00:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 |
| 2 | 30-JUN-2023 07:00:00 |
| 2 | 29-JUN-2023 12:00:00 |

| ID | TIME_STAMP | COMMAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:10:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 26-JUN-2023 08:10:00 | 2 |

If I have the SQL below, I get the each of the 'TIME_OUT's that are greater than the 'TIME_IN', as expected, as the table below.

```
SELECT 
A.ID,
A."TIME_IN",
MOVE.TIME_OUT,
FROM TIMESIN A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
  ID,
  TIME_STAMP AS "TIME_OUT"
  FROM MOVEMENTTAB M
  WHERE COMMAND = 2
) 
MOVE ON MOVE.ID = A.ID AND HIST.TIME_OUT > A.TIME_IN
```

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-JUN-2023 12:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:00:00 | 29-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 29-JUN-2023 08:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 | 28-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 | 29-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 28-JUN-2023 03:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 | 27-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 | 28-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 | 29-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 27-JUN-2023 19:00:00 | 30-JUN-2023 12:10:00 |

But when I add in `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` and `ORDER BY TIME_OUT` within the 'LEFT JOIN', I get '(null)' values for the 'TIME_OUT'.

---

Tested the below and performance was poor, ~ same time as the answered question using CROSS JOIN LATERAL.

---

I also thought that I could do the SQL above, and then `GROUP BY 'TIME_IN'` and use `MIN(MOVE.TIME_OUT)`.. if my TIMESIN table has loads more columns I want to include, is there a less wordy way of including these columns, such as `MIN(A.*)`, or is it a matter of just doing each as `MIN(A.x)` or `GROUP BY TIME_IN, A.x, A.y`?

Also, is there an issue with this performance wise?

Comment: If you get unintended results having NULL as TIME_OUT, why don't you add "time_stamp IS NOT NULL" to your WHERE clause?

Comment: Because I believe I should have results, and if I put the proposed, I would get 0 rows? I'm getting every TIME_STAMP where the time is greater than using the SQL in my question, and when I insert the 'FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY' I get nothing, and I'm trying to understand why it does that.

Comment: Performance will be poor because DBMS has to scan all the data up to some date, which is moving forward leavindg more and more data in the past. You may use index on `COMMAND,ID,TIME_STAMP` (if they are not the only columns in the table) to reduce the number of blocks to process and improve range operations, but it should be tested with real data and with analysis of actual execution plan.

Comment: @astentx What do you mean by "index on COMMAND, " etc.? There are a lot more columns in the table than in my question.. I've managed to speed it up by using `ORDER BY` and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` in my application. Any further reading on what you've explained would be appreciated.

Comment: @FuzzUK As I wrote, date range scan and `order by` (and `fetch first` as a consequence) may be improved by using [descending/ascending](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/optimizer-access-paths.html#GUID-1853B7EE-53A0-484F-8290-BEF4E299CDA7) index scan to retrieve the required information without an access to entire table: https://dbfiddle.uk/VsfnczBL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL` then:

```sql
SELECT m.id,
       t.time_in,
       m.time_stamp AS time_out
FROM   movementtab m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT time_in
         FROM   timesin t
         WHERE  t.time_in <= m.time_stamp
         AND    t.id = m.id
         ORDER BY t.time_in DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t
       ON (1 = 1);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT id,
       time_in,
       ts AS time_out
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         ts,
         command,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE command WHEN 1 THEN ts END) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) AS time_in
  FROM   (
    SELECT id, time_in AS ts, 1 AS command
    FROM   timesin
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time_stamp, command
    FROM   movementtab
    WHERE  command = 2
  )
)
WHERE  command = 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE timesin (ID, TIME_IN) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '08:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-28' + INTERVAL '03:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-27' + INTERVAL '19:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '07:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE movementtab (ID, TIME_STAMP, COMMAND) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-30' + INTERVAL '12:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-29' + INTERVAL '08:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-28' + INTERVAL '03:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-27' + INTERVAL '19:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-26' + INTERVAL '08:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 12:00:00 | 2023-06-30 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-29 08:00:00 | 2023-06-29 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-28 03:00:00 | 2023-06-28 03:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-27 19:00:00 | 2023-06-27 19:10:00 |
| 1 | *null* | 2023-06-26 08:10:00 |

Or, joining in the other direction:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       t.time_in,
       m.time_stamp AS time_out
FROM   timesin t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT time_stamp
         FROM   movementtab m
         WHERE  t.time_in <= m.time_stamp
         AND    t.id = m.id
         ORDER BY m.time_stamp ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) m
       ON (1 = 1);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT id,
       ts AS time_in,
       time_out
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         ts,
         command,
         LAST_VALUE(CASE command WHEN 2 THEN ts END) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts DESC) AS time_out
  FROM   (
    SELECT id, time_in AS ts, 1 AS command
    FROM   timesin
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, time_stamp, command
    FROM   movementtab
    WHERE  command = 2
  )
)
WHERE  command = 1;
```

Both output:

| ID | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 12:00:00 | 2023-06-30 12:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-29 08:00:00 | 2023-06-29 08:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-28 03:00:00 | 2023-06-28 03:10:00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-27 19:00:00 | 2023-06-27 19:10:00 |
| 2 | 2023-06-30 07:00:00 | *null* |
| 2 | 2023-06-29 12:00:00 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7u9zpW7W)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still performs poorly, and the main importance of my question is around performance. Using a subquery in the SELECT statement is still running faster.

Comment: @FuzzUK The main focus of your question appears to be "I could do the SQL above, and then GROUP BY 'TIME_IN' and use MIN(MOVE.TIME_OUT).. if my TIMESIN table has loads more columns I want to include, is there a less wordy way of including these columns, such as MIN(A.*), or is it a matter of just doing each as MIN(A.x) or GROUP BY TIME_IN, A.x, A.y?" and the performance question appears to be a separate issue that is tacked onto the end as an afterthought. Perhaps you need to tidy up the question and make it clear exactly what single question you need answering and what the expected output is.

Comment: My previous question was answered by yourself perfectly, so my question was meant to be surrounding how to achieve this with better performance, sorry if it wasn't formulated great - I certainly appreciate all of the solutions you have provided! I need to do some reading on what @astentx commented on my question surrounding performance.